# Multiple textures in single metal Layer in ios

Tags: swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I am currently working on metal(ios). I could render a single texture on metalLayer recently. But problem arise when i try to render another texture on same metal layer. Would any please explain if there is any possibility to render multiple textures on single metal layer?

Comment: Exactly what effect do you want to achieve? Do you want multiply the two images, add them, layer one over the other (source-over compositing), or something else? There are at least three ways to do what you want (fixed-function blending, framebuffer fetch, multitexturing), but which one you should use depends on the situation.

Comment: thanks warrenm for your reply.I just need to copy image and paste somewhere else using metal

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622942/repitition-of-texture-on-pan-gesture-in-metal-shading-language